# Trouble converting string from commandline to array of floats

Tags: c++

```
char * temp_array;

strcpy(temp_array, argv[i + 1]);

            for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                fann_input[j] = atoi(temp_array[j]);
                printf("%f\n", fann_input[j]);
                printf("o%c\n", temp_array[j]);
            }
```

fann_input is a  float array.

on the atoi line, I get the error:

```
src/main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, const char**)’:
src/main.cpp:117: error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’
src/main.cpp:117: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘int atoi(const char*)’
```

Any ideas?

each of the characters is either a 1 or a 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The prototype of `main` is `int main(int argc, char **argv)`, even though `argv` should be considered constant.
2. You're copying into a random part of memory because `temp_array` is not initialized.
3. You're calling `atoi` on individual characters instead of on a string.
4. `atoi` converts to `int`, not to `float`, although that shouldn't be a problem with {0,1} inputs.

To convert an individual digit in a string `s` to a `float`, do

```
float x = s[i] - '0';
```

(Assuming an ASCII- or EBCDIC-compatible character set where 1 follows 0. I've never heard of a character set where that isn't true.)

Answer (score 3):

All kinds of Bad here:

1. You are trying to copy a string in to an uninitialized `char*` (`temp_array` is declared but never initialized)
2. `atoi` expects a pointer to a whole string, but you are passing it a single char (`temp_array[j]`)
3. `fann_input` is an array of `float` (you say) but you are trying to fill it with `int`s (which is what `atoi` returns)
4. You are using C constructs (pointers, `atoi`, etc) in C++
5. You are coying the same command line argument over and over.

Do something more along these lines.  Uncompiled psudocode follows.  Error handling is left as an excercise for you.

```
for( int j = 0; j < 8; ++j )
{
  stringstream ss;
  ss << argv[j+1]; // copy cmd line param to stream
  float val = 0.0f;
  ss >> val;  // convert to a float
  fann_input[j] = val;  // save it!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`temp_array[i]` is just what the compiler is telling you it is - a `char`.  `atoi()` takes a string as its only parameter.  You need to correct your algorithm to pass a string to `atoi()`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the complete code?

You use "i" outside the loop, then you redefine it in the for loop, and then it looks like you're trying to convert each CHARACTER of the string into its own float?

Comment: ah, prob getting index goof ups. I forgot I was already inside the loop. I would post all my code, but it's > 200 lines /p

Comment: Okay. Well, is converting each character what you want to do? because atoi() takes an entire "string" (null terminated char array)

Comment: each of the characters is a number =\

Answer (score 0):

For one yo don't actually allocate any space in temp_array.  That will give you a great *runtime* bug.

The following line of code is wrong and giving you your errors:

```
fann_input[i] = atoi(temp_array[i]
```

You are passing 1 character to atoi when it expects a string.

Also

```
strcpy(temp_array, argv[i + 1]);
```

Is using i before it is declared.

Comment: it's not, it's in an outer loop. I didn't post all my code, cause there is a ton.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't allocated any space for `temp_array` so you'll write to random locations when you `strcpy` into it. You're treating `temp_array` as an array of strings when it's an array of characters, and then trying to convert single characters to a float. `atoi` will convert to an `int` NOT to a `float` or `double`. You need to use `atof`.

What about a C++-esque way like this, even better would use streams:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    typedef std::vector<std::string> Args;
    Args args(&argv[1], &argv[argc]);
    std::vector<double> results;

    for(Args::const_iterator i = args.begin(); i != args.end(); ++i)
    {
        results.push_back(atof(i->c_str()));
    }

    return 0;
}
```